# Add array to existing array...which is within another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array which gets populated with database values (except for 'PickItems' in this example):

```
$params = array(
    'DeliveryCompanyName' => $row['company_name'],
    'DeliveryAddress1' => $row['address1'],
    'DeliveryAddress2' => $row['address2'],
    'DeliveryCity' => $row['city'],
    'DeliveryCounty' => $row['province'],
    'DeliveryPostCode' => $row['postcode'],
    'DeliveryCountry' => $row['country'],
    'DeliveryPhone' => $row['phone'],
    'DeliveryContact' => $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'],
    'OutboundRef' => $row['order_number'],
    'PickItems' => array(
        array(
            'SKUNumber' => 'SKU',
            'Quantity' => '1',
            'Comments' => 'Comments'
        )
    ),
    'BranchID' => '',
    'CustRef' => $row['order_number']
);
```

Within this array, is an item called "PickItems" which contains an array of array's which are each seperate products ordered.

I am trying to wrap my head around using a while loop on another database query to populate these "PickItems".

Here is the code which I started off writing in order to loop through the database that contains the individual items for the order, and I need to put these into an array and put that array into the main array. The part I am struggling with is putting these values and keys into the array, I thought array_push was the way to go but another answer on another question says you can't do this.

```
if ($result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM order_items WHERE client_id = {$client} AND main_order_id = {$row['platform_order_id']}")) {

    $Items = array();

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        //Add the following values to the items array
        //'SKUNumber' => $row2['sku'],
        //'Quantity' => $row2['quantity'],
        //'Comments' => $row2['comments']
    }
}
```

I suspect that the main array needs to change to something like this? :

```
$params = array(
    'DeliveryCompanyName' => $row['company_name'],
    'DeliveryAddress1' => $row['address1'],
    'DeliveryAddress2' => $row['address2'],
    'DeliveryCity' => $row['city'],
    'DeliveryCounty' => $row['province'],
    'DeliveryPostCode' => $row['postcode'],
    'DeliveryCountry' => $row['country'],
    'DeliveryPhone' => $row['phone'],
    'DeliveryContact' => $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'],
    'OutboundRef' => $row['order_number'],
    'PickItems' => array($Items),
    'BranchID' => '',
    'CustRef' => $row['order_number']
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply push it in your while loop:

```
array_push($params['PickItems'], array(
    'SKUNumber' => $row2['sku'],
    'Quantity' => $row2['quantity'],
    'Comments' => $row2['comments']
));
```

### Output

```
'PickItems' => array(
    array(
        'SKUNumber' => 'SKU',
        'Quantity' => '1',
        'Comments' => 'Comments'
    ),
    array(
        'SKUNumber' => 'SKU 2', // Value from $row2['sku']
        'Quantity' => '2', // Value from $row2['quantity']
        'Comments' => 'Comments2' // Value from $row2['comments']
    ),
),
```

For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: i asked myself the same thing

Comment: Perfect! I got myself into a right muddle working this out. I did upvote you to bring it back to 0. Will mark as answer asap.

Answer (score -1):

To add to an array, inside an array, just do this!

For an associative key value array:

```
$params['PickItems']['whatever'] = $row2;
```

Or for a numeric array:

```
$params['PickItems'][] = $row2;
```